# Getting email using ACAccount for Facebook iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, permissions, acaccount

First of all, I don't want to use Facebook SDK, so I managed to do this, which is working, but I don't know how to retrieve user's email, even though it is on my permissions request.

```
ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:accountTypeName];

NSDictionary *options;

if ( [accountTypeName isEqualToString:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook]){
    options = @{
                ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"601517946570890"
                ,ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"email"]
                };
}

[account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
 {
     if (granted == YES)
     {
         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
         {
             _account = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

             NSDictionary *dict = @{
                                    @"name": [_account userFullName] == nil ? [_account username] : [_account userFullName],
                                    @"account_id": [_account identifier],
                                    @"email": @"??"
                                    };

             NSLog(@"account info: %@",dict);
         }
     }
 }];
```

there is no property on ACAccount that returns user e-mail, so I tried to find if it had to be done via SLRequest and couldn't find it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get the user's email address from Facebook, you have to use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) to query the [current user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) using the [Social framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html):

```
SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                     requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                               URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"]
                                        parameters:nil];
request.account = _account; // This is the _account from your code
[request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (error == nil && ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode == 200) {
        NSError *deserializationError;
        NSDictionary *userData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&deserializationError];

        if (userData != nil && deserializationError == nil) {
            NSString *email = userData[@"email"];
            NSLog(@"%@", email);
        }
    }
}];
```

Comment: Your suggestion, unfortunately, does not guarantee that the email will be a part of the user data dictionary. All I've seen, thus far, is ID and name being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to pass param in GET request. by default only ID & name.

```
NSDictionary *param = @{@"fields":@"email,name"};

SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                     requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                               URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me"]
                                                        parameters:param];
```